# Having two jar files with same name in a single project netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

what I want to do is to have two jar files added to a single Netbeans project. I have two classes that use two versions of a third party component. The component looks for its license file in the project's jar files. My problem is that the license files have the same name and although using the first component its fine because it finds its license file the second one has a problem. It looks for its license and finds the first license and reports an invalid license problem.

Is there a way to add both jar files in a single project in Netbeans and then specify in the code which jar file to use in each case?

Thanks

Comment: If don't have access to jar files source, and can't change them, your job will be hard, otherwise you could change them so each looks-up a specific path, or looks-up in their own jar files.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two files with the same name and path in two different jars then the order of their priority is uncertain. Anyone can be picked during deployment. Its better to change the file names or move the common file into your main project instead of the jars.